# Understanding output shape for 1D convolution

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

I'm trying to get my head around 1D convolution - specifically, how the padding comes into it.

Suppose I have an input sequence of shape `(batch,128,1)` and run it through the following Keras layer:

```
tf.keras.layers.Conv1D(32, 5, strides=2, padding="same")
```

I get an output of shape `(batch,64,32)`, but I don't understand why the sequence length has reduced from 128 to 64... I thought the `padding="same"` parameter kept the output length the same as the input? I suppose that's only true if `strides=1`; so in this case I'm confused about what `padding="same"` actually means.

Answer (score 0):

According to the TensorFlow documents in your case we have:

- filters (Number of filters - output dimension) = 32
- kernelSize (The filter size) = 5
- strides (The unit to move in input data by the convolution layer in each dimensions after applying each convolution) = 2

So applying input in shape `(batch, 128, 1)` will be to apply 32 kernels (in shape 5) and jump two unit after each convolution - so we have `128 / 2 = 64` value corresponding to each filter and at the end output would be in shape `(batch, 64, 32)`.

`padding="same"` is just determining the the convolution on borders. For more details you can check [here](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/types-of-padding-in-convolution-layer/).